# is there any way to execute script commands by reading from github and executing in airflow in different server

Tags: bash, ssh, airflow

We have all the scripts available in github and need to execute the shell/python scripts by login into a different server.

```
Sample script: hello.sh

echo "Hello World"
echo "Printing text with newline"
echo -n "Printing text without newline"
echo -e "\nRemoving \t backslash \t characters\n"
cp a b
```

As we can use ssh operator and can only execute commands but how to run the complete script reading from git hub and execute in different unix server.

We cannot copy the scripts into unix server and need to execute the scripts by reading from git hub. Is there any way to do it in Airflow.

Comment: What does the "sample script" have to do with your actual question? Please try to focus the question on a specific technical problem that prevented you from accomplishing your goal yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Hi Charles i just added an example with dummy name. Same scenario i am expecting to execute. Pls suggest if i missed to add any details. 
I have tried multiple ways and i am unable to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` to get the script from github and then execute it (if you trust it)

```
bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/your/script) [script-args...]
```